# Find integrable $g$ such that $\left|\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{-tx^2}\right|\leqq g(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-tx^2} dx=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{t}}$ for $t>0$.

I want to differentiate this.

That is, I want to do
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-tx^2} dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{-tx^2} dx=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{t}}=-\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}t^{-\frac{3}{2}}.$$

But in order to do this, I have to find $g(x)$ s.t.

$g(x)$ is indipendent of $t$ and integrable on $(-\infty, \infty)$, and
$\bigg| \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{-tx^2}\bigg| \leqq g(x)$.

Of course, I know $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{-tx^2}=-x^2e^{-tx^2}$ but I couldn't find such $g$.

What $g$ works ?

Comment: You probably will actually want to use the mean value theorem (on the integrand in the "limit" def of derivative of the integral) to bound / justify passing the limit to the derivative rigorously. That said... suppose you want to calculate you want to calculate derivative at $t=a>0$. Then you can take the $t$ in the limit to lie in $(a/2, 3a/2)$....

Comment: more than one 'typo' in my previous comment - but one matters: I meant "passing the limit through/past the integral sign"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no such $g$. If $x^2e^{-tx^2}\le g(x)$ for every $t\in(0,\delta)$ then $x^2\le g(x)$, so $g$ is not integrable.

Answer (score 3):

"But in order to do this, I have to find $g(x)$ s.t. $g(x)$ is independent of $t$ and integrable on $(-\infty, \infty)$, and $\bigg| \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{-tx^2}\bigg| \leqq g(x)$." No, that's not right. Given some $t_0>0$ you only need that estimate in a small open interval centered at $t_0$ that stays away from $0.$

Comment: Set $f_t(x)= f(t,x) = e^{-tx^2}$. My comment above to the OP was that - at the get go - one wants an estimate for $${f_t(x) -f_{t_0}(x) \over t - t_0},$$ for some interval around $t_0$ away from $0$ (so that one can appy LDCT, to pass the limit past the integral sign, as the OP wants)... In effect, that will boil down to bounding, as you write, ${\partial \over \partial t}f(t,x)$ in some interval around $t_0$ , but that is because of the MVT, and thus after the fact. Do you agree, or are you thinking of some other approach?

Comment: @peterag Yes I agree, except we don't need to mention MVT (unless you want to) as that is used in the proof of the already known result. The main point is to localize.